# Problem in n dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra

If $x$, $y$ in $R^n$ are such that
                   $\lvert x+ty\rvert \geq \lvert x\rvert$ for all $t \in R$,
then how do I show that $x\cdot y=0$?

Comment: In  $t(\|y\|^2 t - 2 x \cdot y) \ge 0$ let $t \to \pm 0$  (depending on the sign of $x \cdot y$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\vert}$
$\large x\ \mbox{and}\ y\ \mbox{are}\ \underline{vectors}\ \mbox{in}\ {\mathbb R}^{n}$.
$$
\abs{x + ty} \geq \abs{x}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
t\left(ty^{2} + 2x\bullet y\right) \geq 0
$$

If $y \not= 0$, we'll get
$$
\left(\vphantom{\Huge A}\left(\vphantom{\Large A}~t \leq 0~\right)
\quad\vee\quad
\left( t \geq -\,{2x\bullet y \over y^{2}}\right)\right)
\qquad\vee\qquad
\left(\vphantom{\Huge A}\left(~t \leq -\,{2x\bullet y \over y^{2}} \right)
\quad\vee\
\left(\vphantom{\Large A}~t \geq 0~\right)\right)
$$

Then, $\abs{x + ty} \geq \abs{x}$ will not be true $\forall\ t \in {\mathbb R}$. Then, $y = 0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \color{#ff0000}{\large x\bullet y = 0}$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are vectors, not numbers ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Sorry. I was misleading. I'll check tomorrow. Now, it's too late.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=0$ the claim is correct.  Let's $y\neq0$ and $t=-\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|y\|^2}$. Now verify that 
$$\|x+ty\|^2=\|x\|^2-\frac{\langle x,y\rangle^2}{\|y\|^2}.$$

Michael